# How to correctly denormalize a node with paragraph fields

Tags: 8

I am trying to programmatically move some content from one site to another using normalizers from the relaxed module. So far it's working great but when I am trying to deserialize paragraphs entities prior to deserializing their parent nodes they get new revision ids (probably because I am using the multiversion module) rendering the target_revision_id key in the serialized parent node array useless.

Is there a way to save the deserialized paragraph items without changing their revision id?

This is how each deserialized paragraph is saved:

```
$entity->enforceIsNew(TRUE);
$entity->setNewRevision(FALSE);
$entity->save();
```

I believe the multiversion module I am using is the reason I get a new revision id. Any ideas? Do I need to change the revision_id value directly in the database?